# How can I add an in-game level editor?

Tags: unity, scene, world-editor, user-generated-content

I have 200 prefabs and a scene with an infinite flat plane.

I want to allow user to edit the scene - add, remove, rotate, place that prefabs and save/load resulting "scene" in some custom format.

How can I implement this?

Comment: welcome the GDSE. As originally stated, this is a rather broad question - what sorts of things have you tried so far & what specific problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a movable camera and implement a raycast that can select gameobjects, then implement a way to edit that selected gameobject modifying it's transform or even more components through either a simple UI with slider, text or buttons o a similar tool to the one that Unity is using.

Then the last thing you'll have to implement is a save system, you can either go for binary (not readable but better performance) or xml/json (readable but less performant).

If you have any question about how to do any of these just ask away.